# how to make methods and functions work - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, methods

The following method and function are not working, could someone help me?

```
hasMoreOscarsThan - this method accepts one actor object as a parameter and
    returns true if the actor has more Oscars than the one that is passed as
    a parameter and false otherwise.
```

Now write the following functions:

```
getActorByName - this function expects a string as a parameter and returns
    the object in the actors array whose name property is equal to the
    string that is passed in (if there is one).
```

My code:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, age, numOscars) {

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.numOscars = numOscars;
    this.hello = function() { console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.firstName); }
    this.hasMoreOscarsThan = function(x, y) {
        if (this.numOscars > this.numOscars) {
            return this.firstName;
        } else {
            return "False!";
        }
    }

};


var actors = new Array();
actors[0] = new Person("Leonardo", "DiCaprio", 41, 1);
actors[1] = new Person("Jennifer", "Lawrence", 25, 1);
actors[2] = new Person("Samuel L.", " Jackson", 67, 0);
actors[3] = new Person("Meryl", "Streep", 66, 3);
actors[4] = new Person("John", "Cho", 43, 0);

actors.forEach(function(item) {
    item.hello();
})

actors.forEach(function(item) {
    item.hasMoreOscarsThan();
})


function getActorByName(person) {
    console.log(actors.firstName + " " + actors.lastName);
}


function list() {
    var actorsLength = actors.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < actorsLength; i++) {
        getActorByName(actors[i]);
    }
}


var search = function(lastName) {
    var actorsLength = actors.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < actorsLength; i++) {
        if (lastName == actors[i].lastName) {
            getActorByName(actors[i]);
        }
    }
}


search("DiCaprio");

var getAverageAge;

getAverageAge = (actors[0].age + actors[1].age + actors[2].age + actors[3].age + actors[4].age) / actors.length;
console.log(getAverageAge);
```

thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: Change `console.log(actors.firstName + " " + actors.lastName);` to `console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);`.   Check here - https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/rdyL6uqd/

Comment: A formatting tip: Paste your code to https://jsfiddle.net/, Click "Settings", uncheck "Indent with tabs", select "Indent size: 4 spaces". Make sure the first line starts from column 1, i.e. there's no indentation at all. Then click "Tidy", copy the code, and paste it to the post. Then select the code, and click `{}` button on editor tools, or press CTRL+K on your keyboard. That way the code formatting on the post will always be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, age, numOscars) {

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.numOscars = numOscars;
    this.hello = function() { console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.firstName); }
    this.hasMoreOscarsThan = function(x) { // x is a compare parameter
        if (this.numOscars > x) { // comparing numOscars with argument x
            return this.firstName;
        } else {
            return "False!";
        }
    }

};


var actors = new Array();
actors[0] = new Person("Leonardo", "DiCaprio", 41, 1);
actors[1] = new Person("Jennifer", "Lawrence", 25, 1);
actors[2] = new Person("Samuel L.", " Jackson", 67, 0);
actors[3] = new Person("Meryl", "Streep", 66, 3);
actors[4] = new Person("John", "Cho", 43, 0);

actors.forEach(function(item) {
    item.hello();
})

actors.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.hasMoreOscarsThan(2)); // I put compare argument 2 and print result to console
})


function getActorByName(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName); // changed actors to person
}


function list() {
    var actorsLength = actors.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < actorsLength; i++) {
        getActorByName(actors[i]);
    }
}


var search = function(lastName) {
    var actorsLength = actors.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < actorsLength; i++) {
        if (lastName == actors[i].lastName) {
            getActorByName(actors[i]);
        }
    }
}


search("DiCaprio");

var getAverageAge;

getAverageAge = (actors[0].age + actors[1].age + actors[2].age + actors[3].age + actors[4].age) / actors.length;
console.log(getAverageAge);
```

As a result:

> Hello, my name is Leonardo
>
> Hello, my name is Jennifer
>
> Hello, my name is Samuel L.
>
> Hello, my name is Meryl
>
> Hello, my name is John
>
> False!
> False!
> False!
> Meryl
> False!
> Leonardo DiCaprio
> 48.4

Answer (score 0):

The argument is `person`object but you are referring to some `actors` which is not defined  anywhere inside the function, So changed to `person.firstName` & `person.lastName`

```
function getActorByName(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/73stnxtf/)